# \n\n in array gets ignored

Tags: php, echo

I have this Array (part of)

```
[result] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array        
(
"speciesId": 267,
"source": "Beruf: Verzauberkunst (525)\n\nFormel: Verzauberte Laterne",
)
    )
```

If I echo out the source everything is in the same line. The \n\n gets ignored.

I want that after \n in the **source** the output comes in a new line. How is this possible?

Comment: Please add the full source code you have which creates this array

Comment: Have a look at `nl2br()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: `\n` is not a new line in a browser.,`<br>` is. Use the above function, or if not outputting to a browser please clarify where you are.

Comment: A simple `str_replace('\n', "\\n\n", $text);` will do.

Comment: I´ve used the str_replace and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quote ("string") instead of single quote('string') when creating array element.

PHP only interprets escaped characters (with the exception of the escaped backslash \ and the escaped single quote \') when in double quotes (")

This works (results in a newline): "\n"

This does not result in a newline: '\n'